# Assistance with a Login System & Printing a Text File

Tags: python, authentication, text, printing

I have a program that asks the user for a username and password, then checks a text file to see if that username/password are in there. Then it is supposed to print the contents of the text file to screen. A couple of issues:

1. It ALWAYS takes two attempts to successfully log in, even if the username/password are correct.
2. On successful login, the contents of the text file are not printed.

Would very much appreciate some guidance on why these things are happening, and how they can be resolved!

```
def option3():
 print('\nGelos Enterprise User Accounts\n') 

 global index_num,userName,passWord,balances,username,password
 username=input("Enter your username : ")
 password=input("Enter your password : ")
 fileRead=open('accounts.txt','r')
 fileContents = fileRead.read()
 flag=False
 while True:
    line=fileRead.readline()
    lineLength=len(line)
    if lineLength==0:
        break
    lineItem=line.split()
    if username.strip()==lineItem[0] and password.strip()==lineItem[1] :
        print("\nHello",username,"you have logged in successfully."'\n')
        print("Displaying all usernames and passwords: \n")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(fileContents)
        flag=True
        break

 if flag==False:
    print("\nThe user is not found.Please re-enter your username and password.\n")
    option1()
```

Comment: Are you really storing usernames and passwords in a .txt file in plain text? That's not good practice; at the least, passwords should be stored as a hash value, using an appropriate hash function. See here for some information: https://www.vaadata.com/blog/how-to-securely-store-passwords-in-database/

By the way, you never close the file after opening.

Comment: Yes I am because that is what the requirement is for the project in the course I am completing. This is not a real world application. Is not closing the file causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.

```
def print_file_contents(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)

def option3():
    print('\nGelos Enterprise User Accounts\n') 

    global index_num,userName,passWord,balances,username,password
    username=input("Enter your username : ")
    password=input("Enter your password : ")
    file = 'accounts.txt'
    flag = False
    for line in open(file).readlines():
        lineItem=line.split()
        if username.strip() == lineItem[0] and password.strip() == lineItem[1] :
            print("\nHello",username,"you have logged in successfully."'\n')
            print("Displaying all usernames and passwords: \n")
            time.sleep(2)
            print_file_contents(file)
            flag=True
            break

    if not flag:
        print("\nThe user is not found.Please re-enter your username and password.\n")
        option1()
```

However I haven't really modified what the code does, and I suspect the issue comes with how the text file is formatted.

I also assume this is a project and not actual passwords stored in a .txt file which wouldn't be a great idea.

Comment: Confirmed that this is a project for a programming course I am doing, not a real world project. The text file contains the username first followed by a space then then the password. Thanks for your suggestion I'll give it a try.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks so much for your help! I can see what you did to make it work, thanks!